# How do I add values from a list into each item of an RDD?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

Say i have regular python list `[1,2]`
and I have a rdd with 2 items like `[('hi', 'bye'), ('hi', 'bye')]`
and I want each item to become

```
('hi', 'bye', 1)
('hi', 'bye', 2)
```

Essentially appending each item from the list to each item in the rdd.
I feel like this should be simple but I can't think of the logic :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`zip`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.2/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD.zip) method of RDD:

```
rdd1 = sc.parallelize([('hi', 'bye'), ('hi', 'bye')])
rdd2 = sc.parallelize([1, 2])

rdd3 = rdd1.zip(rdd2).map(lambda x: (x[0][0], x[0][1], x[1]))

rdd3.collect()
# [('hi', 'bye', 1), ('hi', 'bye', 2)]
```

Comment: Nice, though if `x[0][0]` is 'hi', wouldn't `x[1]` be the whole list `[1,2]`? How is it separated?

Comment: Because after the zipping operation, both rdd1 and rdd2 are separated. You can have a look at the result of `rdd1.zip(rdd2).collect()` to understand more.

Answer (score 0):

Try matching pattern

```
a = [1,2]
b = [('hi', 'bye'), ('hi', 'bye')]
```

```
print([(x, y, z) for ((x, y), z) in zip(b, a)])
```

**Output:**

```
[('hi', 'bye', 1), ('hi', 'bye', 2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think , this should be resolve your issue .
**Try this code .**

```
your_list = [1,2]
your_rdd = [('hi', 'bye'), ('hi', 'bye')]
print([(x, y, z) for ((x, y), z) in zip(your_rdd, your_list)])
```

**Explanaiton:**

You can use  `str` elements for simplicity.

Suppose ,
You have a RDD and every item is of the form

```
(key, [ele1, ele2, ele3, ..., elen])
```

Every item is a key value pair and the value is a list of elements.

And you want to unpack the list such that I can create a new RDD with every item containing one element as follows:

```
(key, ele1)
(key, ele2)
(key, ele3)
.
.
.
(key, ele4)
```

Such as this , you can use str elements for simplicity.

```
>>> rdd = sc.parallelize([('key', ['ele1', 'ele2'])])
>>> rdd.flatMap(lambda data: [(data[0], x) for x in data[1]]).collect()
[('key', 'ele1'), ('key', 'ele2')]
```